# You don't have permission to access / on this server. Error code 403

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, security, ftp, http-status-code-403

I have read the duplicates. I am having the above error on [my website](http://9amresourceagency.com/). I have tried to change the .htaccess file, the http.conf file and the CHMOD but nothing helped. Please guide me what should I do. Thanks.

**.htaccess**

```
# -FrontPage-
#order deny,allow


<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>

Require all granted
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName 9amllc.com
AuthUserFile /home/p261i9kj/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/p261i9kj/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

**http.conf**

```
<Directory "/">
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/">
 #Options FollowSymLinks
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride None
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you have any index file in `/home/index.html`?

Comment: @anubhava: No. The file lies on the root.

Comment: See what is `DocumentRoot` in Apache config. That path should have a `<Directory>` entry in the same config file. That directory should exist and should have index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

You have `AllowOverride None` in both those directories. They need to be either `All` or `AuthConfig,Limit`.

You can see in the documentation for the [Auth modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#authname) that they require the `AuthConfig` override, and the [mod_authz (allow/deny/order)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) requires the `Limit` override.

Additionally, you have this:

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
```

which seems to both deny from all and allow from all, you only want one or the other (I'm assuming the second).